# Lync 2010 SDK - Calling a response group

Tags: c#, wpf, lync-2010, ucma

I have a response group made of 2 agents. For the sake of clarification let's use the following:

- Agent1: ag1@domain.com
- Agent2: ag2@domain.com
- Response Group: RG@domain.com

My code is based on the following walk through to establish an AV call with an agent:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh378584.aspx

If I establish a call with Agent1 or Agent2 directly using their SIP address, the call goes through and everything works perfectly and I can even render the video from both sides.

If I establish a call with the Response Group however, and even if Agent 1 or Agent 2 take the call, it just ends with no error message and no exceptions thrown on my side.

The Sample application accompanying the SDK (AudioVideoConversation) also exhibits the same problems.

What's the reason for this? Is the SDK capable of handling response groups? If so, then how?

- Edit: (1) Forgot to mention: Lync is in suppression mode!
- Edit: (2) Further investigation lead me to this answer on the Lync Client Development forum: [Forum Answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicatorsdk/thread/9a5a6b2b-6ac5-4542-adf0-0730cdff38e1) which to be honest is quite inconclusive and outrageous since the issue was raised in 2011 and the bug was replicated by MS.
- Edit: (3) Question was raised again in the Lync Client Development forum, pending the Lync team bug reproduction [Forum Answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicatorsdk/thread/13ff0dd6-120a-4449-880e-8a7aeeec0c90)
- Edit: (4) The recent June updates for the client don't solve the issue either.